# Java NoSuchMethodException - method does exist in class

Tags: java, javafx, nosuchmethod

I am building a JavaFx application and I want to create a method that receives a GridPane and a Node[] with the amount of items being added to the pane. However, when I call the method I get a NoSuchMethodException.

As a test, I tried to create a simple method `private String helloWorld()` that would `return "Hello World";`. This method does work, but when I try to run `gridLogin = buildForm(gridLogin, items);`, I get the `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException` error.

**Application.java**

```
public class DesktopApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BuildGraphicalUserInterface ui = new BuildGraphicalUserInterface();
        ui.initStage(primaryStage);
    }
}
```

**BuildGraphicalUserInterface.java**

```
package com.fenrir.desktop.UserInterface;

import ...;

public class BuildGraphicalUserInterface {

    private final String APP_TITLE = "Fenrir Desktop App";
    private final String LOGIN_HEADER = "FENRIR secure";

    Stage stage;
    Scene sceneLogin, sceneMain, sceneRegister;
    GridPane gridLogin, gridMain, gridRegister;

    long startTime, endTime;

    boolean authorized;
    Optional<String> result;

    public void initStage(Stage primaryStage) {
        stage = primaryStage;
//        Set global ui options
        stage.setTitle(APP_TITLE);
        stage.setResizable(false);

//        Setup every screen in application
        initScenes(stage);
    }

    private void initScenes(Stage stage) {
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        sceneLogin = buildLoginScreen();
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("login:\t" + (endTime - startTime));

        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        sceneMain = buildMainScreen();
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("main:\t" + (endTime - startTime));

        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        sceneRegister = buildRegisterScreen();
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("register:\t" + (endTime - startTime));
        stage.setScene(sceneLogin);
        stage.show();
    }

//    BUILD OF SCREENS
    private Scene buildLoginScreen() {
        gridLogin = new GridPane();
        gridLogin.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        gridLogin.setVgap(10);
        gridLogin.setHgap(10);

        Text loginTitle = new Text(LOGIN_HEADER);
        loginTitle.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20));
        Label usernameLabel = new Label("Username:");
        final TextField usernameTextField = new TextField();
        Label companyLabel = new Label("Company:");
        final TextField companyTextField = new TextField();
        Button loginButton = new Button("Login");
        Hyperlink registerLink = new Hyperlink();
        registerLink.setText("Register");

        registerLink.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                stage.setScene(sceneRegister);
            }
        });

        loginButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                UserAuthentication auth = new UserAuthentication(usernameTextField.getText(), companyTextField.getText());
                try {
//                    check if user exists
                    auth.authenticate();

//                    show token pop up
                    promptTokenAlert();
                    if (result.isPresent()) {
                        if (auth.verifyToken(result.get())) {
                            authorized = true;
                            stage.setScene(sceneMain);
                        }
                        else
                            wrongTokenAlert();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    userNotFoundAlert();
                    usernameTextField.setText("");
                    companyTextField.setText("");
                }
            }});

        Node[] items = new Node[6];
        items[0] = loginTitle;
        items[1] = usernameLabel;
        items[2] = usernameTextField;
        items[3] = companyLabel;
        items[4] = companyTextField;
        items[5] = loginButton;
        items[6] = registerLink;
        gridLogin = buildForm(gridLogin, items);

        sceneLogin = new Scene(gridLogin, 300, 200);

        return sceneLogin;
    }

    private Scene buildMainScreen() {
        gridMain = new GridPane();

        final Label authorizedLabel = new Label("Authorized!");
        Button logoutButton = new Button("Logout");

        logoutButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                authorized = false;
                stage.setScene(sceneLogin);
            }});

        gridMain.add(authorizedLabel, 0, 0);
        gridMain.add(logoutButton, 0, 1);
        sceneMain = new Scene(gridMain, 800, 600);

        return sceneMain;
    }

    private Scene buildRegisterScreen() {
        gridRegister = new GridPane();
        gridRegister.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        gridRegister.setVgap(10);
        gridRegister.setHgap(10);
        sceneRegister = new Scene(gridRegister, 300, 200);

        Label userName = new Label("Username:");
        final TextField userTextField = new TextField();
        Label company = new Label("Company:");
        final TextField companyTextField = new TextField();
        Label phoneNumber = new Label("Phone nr.:");
        final TextField phoneNumberTextField = new TextField();
        Button registerButton = new Button("Register");
        Hyperlink returnLabel = new Hyperlink();
        returnLabel.setText("Go back");

        returnLabel.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                stage.setScene(sceneLogin);
            }
        });
        registerButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                /**
                 * register response
                 * 1 - user already exists
                 * 2 - incorrect username
                 * 3 - incorrect phonenumber
                 * 4 - unknown error
                 * 0 - success
                 */
                int registerResponse;
                UserRegistration userReg = new UserRegistration(userTextField.getText(), companyTextField.getText(), phoneNumberTextField.getText());
                try {
                    registerResponse = userReg.Register();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    registerResponse = 4;
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (registerResponse == 0) {
                    userRegisteredConfirmation();
                    stage.setScene(sceneLogin);
                } else {
                    userRegistrationErrorAlert(registerResponse);
                }
            }
        });

        gridRegister.add(userName, 0, 1);
        gridRegister.add(userTextField, 1, 1);
        gridRegister.add(company, 0, 2);
        gridRegister.add(companyTextField, 1, 2);
        gridRegister.add(phoneNumber, 0, 3);
        gridRegister.add(phoneNumberTextField, 1, 3);
        gridRegister.add(registerButton, 1, 4);
        gridRegister.add(returnLabel, 0, 4);

        return sceneRegister;
    }

    /**
     * Builds a form with items received (items should be sorted)
     * @param grid
     * @param items
     * @return
     */
    private GridPane buildForm(GridPane grid, Node[] items) {
        int row = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            grid.add(items[i], i, row);
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                row++;
        }

        return grid;
    }

//    ALERTS
    /**
     * Alert is shown when service returns no user
     * @return
     */
    private Alert userNotFoundAlert() {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("FENRIR security");
        alert.setHeaderText("Error");
        alert.setContentText("User not recognized");
        alert.showAndWait();
        return alert;
    }

    /**
     * Alert is shown when user should enter token
     * @return
     */
    private TextInputDialog promptTokenAlert() {
        TextInputDialog alert = new TextInputDialog("");
        alert.setTitle("FENRIR security");
        alert.setHeaderText("Token requested");
        result = alert.showAndWait();
        return alert;
    }

    /**
     * Alert is shown when entered token is wrong
     * @return
     */
    private Alert wrongTokenAlert() {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("FENRIR security");
        alert.setHeaderText("Token incorrect");
        alert.showAndWait();
        return alert;
    }

    /**
     * Confirmation is shown when registration is completed
     * @return
     */
    private Alert userRegisteredConfirmation() {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("FENRIR security");
        alert.setHeaderText("Success");
        alert.setContentText("Registration completed");
        alert.showAndWait();
        return alert;
    }

    /**
     * Alert is shown when an error occurs during registration
     * @param errorCode
     * @return
     */
    private Alert userRegistrationErrorAlert(int errorCode) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("FENRIR security");
        alert.setHeaderText("Error");
        String errorMessage;
        switch (errorCode) {
            case 1: errorMessage = "User already exists.";
                break;
            case 2: errorMessage = "Incorrect username. Username should be at least 2 characters.";
                break;
            case 3: errorMessage = "Incorrect phone number. Should be 8 characters and only numbers.";
                break;
            default: errorMessage = "Unknown error. Contact administrator.";
        }
        alert.setContentText(errorMessage);
        alert.showAndWait();
        return alert;
    }
}
```

**Stack trace**

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.fenrir.desktop.DesktopApplication.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:125)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I guess javaFX using an external compiler to compiler your new code. After saving your code, externally "build" your project again.

Comment: @AfsinBuyuksarac Using IntelliJ; restarted, made project, invalidate cache - nothing worked. Thanks for suggesting tho.

Comment: BuildGraphicalUserInterface or BuildGUI.java?

Comment: Add the full stack trace to your question, please.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Stack trace added.

Comment: please post all the code with file names,its very confusing

Comment: So... it is not finding your `main` method.

Comment: @Lars you have not written main method or your you ide not finding main method in class. post your main method class

Comment: @RealSkeptic It's a JavaFX application, meaning that `start()` is the starting point. When I remove the `buildForm()` and run my application as it was, it works.

Comment: Yes, but what it says is that it doesn't find `main`, which means that something has gone wrong along the way. It's not that it is not finding `buildForm`. It means that adding that call disrupts the JavaFX launch mechanism.

Comment: Interesting error. I can't think of anything how to fix this, as I never needed a `main` in my JavaFX applications. Not sure where I need to place this method if it is needed per se.

Comment: Well, try to add a `main` method anyway. All it needs to do is call `launch(args)`. It could be that Intellij is not including the JavaFX launcher in the resulting Jar or that the build changed somehow. This will at least give you an error somewhere else where it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your problem, install e(fx)clipse this plugin for eclise but i dont know for intellij ,or add facet for your application as javafx application, if you add facet you dont need main method , or use like this

```
public class DesktopApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BuildGraphicalUserInterface ui = new BuildGraphicalUserInterface();
        ui.initStage(primaryStage);
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       launch(args);
   }
}
```